# Bind byobu window to Ctrl+Shift+T shortcut

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, byobu

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut runs the `gnome-terminal` by default. I have installed `byobu`, and I want this shortcut to open the latest used byobu session. When pressed multiple times, I should still have just one window.

I tried to map this shortcut to `gnome-terminal`, but this open multiple windows, with the same session.

The behavior I want is the same as clicking on the terminal icon in the dash. After the above map I have a behavior of "New terminal" which can be accessed by the right click on this icon. It's probably about some gnome-terminal parameter, but I don't see any related one.

Comment: **Ctrl+Alt+T**, not **Ctrl+Shift+T**, shortcut runs the gnome-terminal!!!

Answer (score 2):

Just add next line at the end of `~/.bashrc` file (you can open it with `gedit ~/.bashrc` command from terminal):

```
byobu
```

or

```
byobu-screen
```

Comment: This opens the same session, but still opens multiple windows when opening with ctrl+shift+T shortcut. Furthermore, I get the session nesting warrning error.

Comment: @takeshin Normally, **Ctrl+Shift+T shortcut open a new tab**, not a window and in no case more windows. **Ctrl+Alt+T** is for open a new window. Also, I don't get any warning. So this is sound like a bug. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug in this sense.

Comment: I had a different shortcut for gnome-terminal, changed it, session warnings are gone, but I have still multiple windows opened.

Comment: As I said, this sound like a bug. This doesn't happen if you have the original shortcuts for gnome-terminal.

Comment: if byobu-enable didn`t work for you > https://askubuntu.com/questions/866115/how-can-byobu-be-automatically-started-when-opening-a-new-terminal

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom keyboard shorcut and add the following command:

```
gnome-terminal --app-id us.kirkland.terminals.byobu -e byobu
```

I copied the command from the application desktop icon in:

```
/usr/share/applications/byobu.desktop
```