# How can byobu be automatically started when opening a new terminal?

Tags: byobu, zsh, xfce4-terminal

I am using xfce4-terminal as standard terminal and want to start byobu automatically when I am opening a new terminal. My shell is zsh.

How can this be achieved? I found other posts like this [one](https://superuser.com/questions/381939/how-can-i-run-byobu-from-xterm-at-starting#382392) but this only seems to work `byobu-enable` only seems to work for login-shells, not when opening a new xfce4-terminal.

Comment: Have you tried moving the lines added by `byobu-enable` to your `.zshrc` instead of the `.profile`?

Comment: Thank you, solved my problem. In my case, it only works at the beginning of `.zshrc`, not at the end. Do you want to post your comment as answer? Then I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Z-Shell uses `.zprofile` and `.zshrc` instead of `.profile` and `.bashrc`.

Since `byobu-enable` adds the required commands to load `byobu` in the `.profile` (as mentioned in the question you mention), you should at least move it to the `.zprofile` but if you want it to load everytime you load a new shell, `.zshrc` is the one to go for.

That is because `.zprofile` gets sourced once when opening a session, while `.zshrc` is the one that's read upon starting a new terminal so it will apply to every terminal start.

Comment: I moved each line from `.profile` and `.bashrc` to the respective zsh files and it still doesn't launch byobu for me :(